# How can I connect front-end js with back-end js

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm currently working on a website and I need to let the user send an email from that website. (The email should be sent through a designated email).
So I'm going to use nodemailer, but since the JS is connected to the HTML-Elements, I can't import any libraries. So I created another JS file that runs back-end, but how do I connect the two? For the “JS Events” it would have to be connected to an HTML-Element.. And well, just calling a function doesn't work.
Things like requireJS don't seem like a good choice either since **I'd like to handle it back-end**.

Comment: generically the term you're looking for is probably `AJAX` - specifically, in the browser you'd use either `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` - on the backend - well, that depends on your server code

Comment: RequireJS isn't a good choice because it is an AMD module loader for browsers and Node Mailer (a) doesn't come in AMD module format and (b) won't run in a browser.

Comment: Users should not be using forms to submit emails to you if you're intending to respond to the user. They should be using their mail client. If for instance you auto respond to the email provided hackers see this and use your services to spam emails knowing they can insert whatever email they want. (Only allow forms for emails if the account has a verified email address to prevent spam and potential fines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two options for communicating between client-side JavaScript and server-side code are:

- HTTP requests
- WebSockets

Approaches for using them include [Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms), (if you are using Node.js for your backend then you are probably using Express, in which case [this is a more specific tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/forms)),  [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), and [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

For your purposes, forms are the simplest option. Ajax is slightly more complicated but you might prefer the extra flexibility in UX.